# How can I set dictionary values to behave like instance properties?

Tags: python, class

I would like to store a number of temperature values as a dictionary instance attribute. Whenever the dictionary key is used, I would like the corresponding value to update, with behaviour similar to that of an instance `@property` decorator.

Is there a way to to this without updating the entire dictionary? Below is code of how I'd expect it to pan out, with simplified update functions (the real ones will read from sensors), but the temperatures need to update on each access.

```py
import random


class Thermal():

    def __init__(self):
        self.temperatures = {'outside': self.outside, 'inside': self.inside}

    @property
    def outside(self):
        return random.random()

    @property
    def inside(self):
        return 1 + random.random()

    @property
    def c(self):
        return random.random()


a = Thermal()
print(a.temperatures['outside'])
print(a.temperatures['outside'])
print(a.temperatures['inside'])
print(a.temperatures['inside'])
```

The `outside` and `inside` temperatures printed above do not change on access, though of course it works for the basic attribute, `c`. Is this a case where I need to create a dict subclass, or is there another way to do it?
I can resign to having individual instance attributes for each temperature, but I think it's neater in a dictionary and am keen to see if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code and keeping the semantics like `a.temperatures['outside']` here is possible solution:

```
import random


class Temperatures():  # here
    def __init__(self, thermal):
        self.thermal = thermal

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.thermal, item)



class Thermal():

    def __init__(self):
        self.temperatures = Temperatures(self)  # and here

    @property
    def outside(self):
        return random.random()

    @property
    def inside(self):
        return 1 + random.random()

    @property
    def c(self):
        return random.random()


a = Thermal()
print(a.temperatures['outside'])
print(a.temperatures['outside'])  # will give different random number
print(a.temperatures['inside'])
print(a.temperatures['inside'])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
class Thermal:

    def __init__(self):
        self._temperatures = {'inside': None, 'outside': None}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.update()
        return self._temperatures[key]

    def update(self):
        # update temperatures here...
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at, though I'd like to be able to update the values independently rather than all at once. A solution to that is to have individual update functions in a dict of their own, and pass the key to the update function - I'll try this now.
As a novice, I'm uncertain how the `__getitem__` method works to spit-out the dictionary values here - is it a special method or do I need to explicitly call e.g. `__getitem__('inside')` to use it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could pass `key` directly from `__getitem__` to `update`, too.